# Class overhead in C++

Tags: c++, performance, class, oop

I have a class e.g.:

```
class Vehicle {
  public:
    Vehicle(int handle);

    // Methods that use the handle e.g.:
    Color getColor() {
        return VEHICLE::GET_COLOR(handle);
    }

  protected:
    int handle;
};
```

I don't know if that example makes sense to you, but I built several wrapper classes around those handles to get a more OOP style of coding.

So my question now is, how much overhead is there when I pass a `Vehicle` object over just passing the vehicle handle to other methods?

Comment: Not unlikely, you possibly introduce overhead with the `handle`

Comment: You need more concrete data. Remember Hoare's Dictum: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Measure the performance with a profiler rather than guessing. (Other factors come into play such as whether you are passing by value or reference, how big the real classes are, what optimization settings you are using, etc.)

Comment: Knuth: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Comment: You'll see the overhead by comparing the object code generated by your compiler for your platform for each implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split your class in a header and source file and use it in other compilation units there will be a sligth overhead due to the call to the constructor.

To solve this, the definition of your constructor has to be placed within your header file, so that the compiler can inline it.

You can do this with either changing your class declaration:

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(int handle)
     : handle(handle)
    {
    }
...
```

or by putting the definition inside your headerfile and decorating it with the `inline` keyword.

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(int handle);
...
}

inline Vehicle::Vehicle(int handle)
 : handle(handle)
{
}
```

Notice that there is no gurantee that your function will be inlined, but probably every major compiler out there will be able to do it.

Also notice, that additional work in your constructor, e.g `handle - 1`, will also very likely result in a overhead.

If your class is polymorphic or bigger, there might be additional overhead.

Comment: _"there will be a sligth overhead due to the call to the constructor"_ there __might__ be. I expect LTO to kick in and inline any calls to simple constructors even if they are defined in diffetent TU.

Answer (score 0):

An optimizing compiler would ensure that there is no overhead for such simple *call forwards*. The core class (used by wrapper) should ideally be in same module (DLL/SO), otherwise linker/optimizer *may be* of little help.

However, for such thin wrappers around core class, even in shared-library scenario, the compiler would simply call the core method, eliminating the wrapper class method from call site.